# Json Formato correto para typeahead?

Tags: java, json, typeahead

Quando gero um JSON com o código abaixo :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("Nome", c.getNome_fantasia().trim());
    jsonObject.put("Apelido", c.getNome_razao_social().trim());
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);                

} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ControllerLogicCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    throw new RuntimeException("Erro pupulando Clientes", ex);                
}
```

O resultado é um JSON no formato:

> [{"Apelido":"Flavio Benini","Nome":"Flavio Benini"}]

Mas o typeahead trabalha com ele no formato abaixo:

> {Nome: ["Flavio Benini"],Apelido: ["Flavio benini"]}

Como gerar ele Formato adequado para o typeahead?

Answer (score 1):

O correto não seria isso?

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Nome", "Flavio Benini");
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Apelido", "Flavio Benini");
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

> [{"Nome":"Flavio Benini"},{"Apelido":"Flavio Benini"}]

Sendo que o formato que você passou é um formato invalido para um json.

Json utilizado pelo typeahead.js [nhl.json](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/nhl.json). Seria isso?

Comment: c.getNome_fantasia().trim() = "Flavio Benini" entendeu!!  O erro é os delimitadores do json!